# Writing a csv file using data from a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv

I am using Pandas and Python to work with some data.

I have a csv file with two full columns, and labels for the remaining 10 columns.
The data has a total of 100 rows, and I have attached a sample of what it looks like.

I have plots of data, with each plot containing an x list and a y list. I would like, for each of these y lists, for every item in the list to be its own row in the correct column in the csv. I have attached some samples of y lists and how I would like to transform this into the csv, and some code I have tried. Thank you so much!
[image]

I have 10 lists, in the following format,
`featureList[0]= [1,123,654,7,2,5,10...]`, where the values at the `[0]` index item belong in the column with a header '1'. For example, I would like it to transform into the following csv.

[image]

```
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
headers = data.columns.values
print(headers)
headers = headers[2:-1]
for item in headers:
    label = int(item)-1
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        data.loc[index, item] = featureL[label][index]
```

But this did not work.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `df.assign(**{item: list_of_values}).to_csv(filename)`

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I have a 2d list, and I would like to write into a csv file with each inner list being one column.

Comment: @PaulH Thank you!

Comment: @PaulH When I do this in a for loop, it only writes the very last column, do you know why this is?

Comment: `df.assign` returns a copy. So if you're doing this in a loop, you're over-writing the CSV each time with a fresh copy of the dataframe. You should build your dictionary in a loop, and do the `assign(**full_dict).to_csv(...)` only once

Comment: @PaulH Would the dictionary map the column label to the list of labels of that column?

Comment: keys are the names of the columns, values are the sequence of values that will populate the columns

Comment: @PaulH Thank you!